# How to have Apache return 404 if not logged in?

Tags: apache, php, http-status-code-404

On my site https://internal.example.com, the /index.php file is a login form. I would like to configure either Apache or PHP to return a 404 error for any file except for /index.php if the user is not logged in (instead of 403, so that it is not obvious what files are on the server). How would I do this?

Comment: As shown in the answers changing the headers is easy. However using the correct 401/403 response need not leak any information about what files are on your server.

Answer (score 2):

returning a 404 header is simple:

```
 <?php
 if($loggedIn == false){
   header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
 } else{
   //some other code
 }
 ?>
```

The problem is just changing the header to 404 will not display the 404 error page but only a blank page with the header set to 404 (search robots will not index the page but people visiting the site will not know what is going on). You will have to add 404 content yourselves.

Example:

```
<?php 
if($loggedIn == False){
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> was not found on this server.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/x.x.xx (Debian) Server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Port x</address>
  </body>
</html>
<?php 
exit;
} else {
  //some other code here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (!$logged_in)){
      header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php